# State get doesn't save on refresh react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo, redux-persist

When my app refreshes it doesn't save state but when I create another habit that's when the state is saved, and I want to save the state when I update a habit or when any part of the state is changed:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        habitListReducer,
        progressRefreshReducer,
        currentDateReducer,
        statisticsReducer,
        productiveDayReducer,
        habitCategoryReducer,
        habitsColorReducer,
    })
    
    
    
    
    
    const persistConfig = {
        key: "root",
        storage: AsyncStorage,
    }
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
    
    const store = createStore(persistedReducer)
    const persistedStore = persistStore(store)
    
    export default function App() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <PersistGate persistor={persistedStore} loading={null}>
                    <NavigationContainer>
                        <BottomTab />
                    </NavigationContainer>
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
```